# get initialized string regex

Tags: php, regex

`kNO = "Get this value now if you can";`

How do I get `Get this value now if you can` from that string? It looks easy but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading [PHP PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) and see the examples. For your question:

```
$str = 'kNO = "Get this value now if you can";';
preg_match('/kNO\s+=\s+"([^"]+)"/', $str, $m);
echo $m[1]; // Get this value now if you can
```

**Explanation:**

```
kNO        Match with "kNO" in the input string
\s+        Follow by one or more whitespace
"([^"]+)"  Get any characters within double-quotes
```

Comment: No need for the `?` in the pattern though.

Answer (score 1):

Use character classes to start extracting from one open quote to the next:

```
$str = 'kNO = "Get this value now if you can";'
preg_match('~"([^"]*)"~', $str, $matches); 
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Explanation:

```
~    //php requires explicit regex bounds
"    //match the first literal double quotation
(    //begin the capturing group, we want to omit the actual quotes from the result so group the relevant results
[^"] //charater class, matches any character that is NOT a double quote
*    //matches the aforementioned character class zero or more times (empty string case)
)    //end group
"    //closing quote for the string.
~    //close the boundary.
```

EDIT, you may also want to account for escaped quotes, use the following regex instead:

```
'~"((?:[^\\\\"]+|\\\\.)*)"~'
```

This pattern is slightly more difficult to wrap your head around. Essentially this is broken into two possible matches (seperated by the Regex OR character `|`)

```
[^\\\\"]+    //match any character that is NOT a backslash and is NOT a double quote
|            //or
\\\\.        //match a backslash followed by any character.
```

The logic is pretty straightforward, the first character class will match all characters except a double quote or a backslash. If a quote or a backslash is found, the regex attempts to match the 2nd part of the group. In the event that it's a backslash, it will of course match the pattern `\\\\.`, but it will also advance the match by 1 character, effectively skipping whatever escaped character followed the backslash. The only time this pattern will stop matching is when a lone, unescaped double quote is encountered,

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're getting that input, you could use [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) or [`parse_ini_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php). Dead simple.